# Manage view position with UIKeyboard prediction on and off

Tags: ios, view, keyboard

I want to move the view up when the keyboard is shown and down when keyboard is hidden like in message. I am able to achieve it, but the i hide the prediction there is some blank space.[image]

I am handling the movement of keyboard with "**UIKeyboardWillShowNotification**" and "**UIKeyboardWillHideNotification**"

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

#pragma mark - keyboard movements
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        CGRect f = self.view.frame;
        f.origin.y = -keyboardSize.height;
        self.view.frame = f;
    }];
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        CGRect f = self.view.frame;
        f.origin.y = 0.0f;
        self.view.frame = f;
    }];
}
```

I want to handle the movement of view like it happens in messages app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
```

replace with below line

```
CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my realization:

```html
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.defaultViewFrame = self.view.frame;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(onKeyboardShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(onKeyboardHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)onKeyboardShow:(NSNotification *)notification {      // method when keyboard appears
    CGFloat keyboardHeight = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;
    [self updateView:YES withKeyboardHeight:keyboardHeight];
}

- (void)onKeyboardHide:(NSNotification *)notification { // method when keyboard hides
    CGFloat keyboardHeight = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;
    [self updateView:NO withKeyboardHeight:keyboardHeight];
}

*****************************

- (void)updateView:(BOOL)show withKeyboardHeight:(CGFloat)height{
    [self.view setFrame:self.defaultViewFrame];      
    
    CGRect newViewRect = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                    self.view.frame.origin.y - height,
                                    self.view.frame.size.width,
                                    self.view.frame.size.height);
    
    if (show) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            [self.view setFrame:newViewRect];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
    }
}
```