# Check if auto prediction pop-over is visible TextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

Is there a way to know when the auto prediciton pop-over becomes visible/hides in a UITextView. I need to move some views up, so the predicitons are not being covered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manage view position with UIKeyboard prediction on and off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38564459/manage-view-position-with-uikeyboard-prediction-on-and-off)